# Entity Framework Core concurrency exception causing rogue queries to execute

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I've been investigating a truly bizarre issue with rogue queries hitting our production databases and attempting to load entire tables (plural) into memory without the data being requested. We have some parts of the application of EF6 and some on EF Core and the original fingers were pointed at client evaluation of queries in EF Core version **2.2.4**. However, even after upgrading to EF Core **3.1.7** and disabling client evaluation, the issue still occurs. (This is a .Net Framework **4.7.2** WebAPI application using Microsoft SqlServer)

I was able to enable debugging logs and found that the issue happens whenever a `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException` is thrown. (For some reason, this exception is only written in debug mode by default and so the correlation went unnoticed for a long time.) The `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` is not a problem in itself but whenever it occurs EF Core starts attempting to load and track all data from all tables in the context until it runs out of memory. In my case the logs look like this:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded.

Several of these debug messages. One for each table `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryExecutionPlanned`

```
queryContext => new QueryingEnumerable<MyTable>( (RelationalQueryContext)queryContext, RelationalCommandCache, null, null, Func<QueryContext, DbDataReader, ResultContext, int[], ResultCoordinator, MyTable>, Namespace.MyContext, null )
```

Then it starts pulling and tracking the data until it gets to one that is big enough that an OOM exception is thrown. I was able to reproduce the issue by explicitly forcing a conflict using code like this

```
public void GenerateConflict(int id)
{
        var element = _context.MyData.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);

        if (element != null)
        {
            element.DisplayName = "test";
            _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw($"Delete from MyData where Id={id}");
        }

        _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

When manually forcing the conflict like this. I can see the same behavior where immediately after, EF Core will try to start loading and tracking from unrelated tables without applying any filters whatsoever.

Why would a concurrency exception cause this behavior? Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Which database provider is this, is lazy loading enabled and which exact EF version is this?

Comment: @GertArnold This is EF Core 3.1.7 with SqlServer on .Net Framework 4.7.2. Lazy loading isn't enabled.

Comment: Bizarre indeed!  Just some thoughts ...  Can you absolutely isolate the problem within EF?  Am thinking ... 1) Use your GenerateConflict method.  2) Create a fresh context inside that method.  3) Make sure you have no overrides of SaveChanges within your context so its all just EF workings.  4) Try/Catch/Swallow the error from SaveChanges() to be sure that nothing further up the call stack or global error handlers are doing something strange.  I guess if you're still left with the problem and have eliminated all possibilities of rogue code outside of EF then its a bug-ticket for MS.

Comment: @NeilW It did turn out to be a problem with a separate package after all Serilog.Exceptions. Added the solution I used in the end in case it helps someone else out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this wasn't a problem with EF Core as much as it was an issue with **Serilog.Exceptions** package. This Github issue pointed me in the right direction https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/15214.

> WARNING: If you are using EntityFrameworkCore with [Serilog.Exceptions](https://github.com/RehanSaeed/Serilog.Exceptions) you must add this, otherwise in certain cases your entire database will be logged! This is because the exceptions in Entity Framework Core have properties that link to the entire database schema in them

I had to add an additional package `Serilog.Exceptions.EntityFrameworkCore` then configure the exception enrichment in Serilog like this:

```
.Enrich.WithExceptionDetails(new DestructuringOptionsBuilder()
    .WithDefaultDestructurers()
    .WithDestructurers(new[] { new DbUpdateExceptionDestructurer() }))
```

With that configuration in place, the conflict exception no longer leads to my entire DB being serialized.